# extend ctrlp without setting `g:ctrlp_extensions`

Tags: vim, ctrlp

I am trying to write my own [CtrlP](https://github.com/ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim) extension.

The [document](https://github.com/ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim/tree/extensions) shows that, we have to set `g:ctrlp_extensions` as follow to make our extension working.

```
let g:ctrlp_extensions = ['extensionname']
```

But it seems these two extension:[ctrlp-funky](https://github.com/tacahiroy/ctrlp-funky), [ctrlp-extensions.vim](https://github.com/sgur/ctrlp-extensions.vim) can still work without setting `g:ctrlp_extensions`(I failed to find this variable in the souce files of this two extension by using `grep -rn "g:ctrlp_extensions" *`).

So my question is:

1. can we extend CtrlP without setting  `g:ctrlp_extensions`
2. if so, how can we do that

Answer (score 1):

After i read the code carfully, i found out that i need to modify `g:ctrlp_ext_vars` for this purpose like this.

First define you own ctrlp_extension_var:

```
let s:ctrlp_extension_var = {
        \ 'init': 'xxx',
        \ 'accept': 'xxx',
        \ 'lname': 'xxx',
        \ 'sname': 'xxx',
        \ }
```

Second, set or add your ctrl_extension_var to `g:ctrlp_ext_vars`:

```
if exists('g:ctrlp_ext_vars') && !empty(g:ctrlp_ext_vars)
  let g:ctrlp_ext_vars = add(g:ctrlp_ext_vars, s:ctrlp_extension_var)
else
  let g:ctrlp_ext_vars = [s:ctrlp_extension_var]
endif
```